# To be overwhelmed by vs to be overwhelmed with

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference, phrasal-verbs

Are the expressions TO BE OVERWHELMED WITH  and TO BE OVERWHELMED BY interchangeable? or is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 5):

There's not really any difference in *meaning* depending on which preposition (***with*** or ***by***) you use. Certainly there are no contexts where two *different* meanings could be distinguished by preposition choice.

BUT there's [fairly strong tendency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overwhelmed%20by%20grief%2Coverwhelmed%20with%20grief&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coverwhelmed%20by%20grief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coverwhelmed%20with%20grief%3B%2Cc0) to use ***with*** for "abstract" referents, such as ***grief, joy, sorrow*** (particularly, with abstract qualities which are or become "internal" to the overwhelmed subject).

And for something more "concrete" such as ***the enemy, invaders***, [we usually use ***by***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overwhelmed%20with%20the%20enemy%2Coverwhelmed%20by%20the%20enemy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coverwhelmed%20by%20the%20enemy%3B%2Cc0) (particularly when the overwhelming force remains essentially "external").

Comment: Thank you very much